# Saving data from JSON to object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a problem with pushing data from json to object.

This solution works for me but I am not happy with it. Look at the service.
Is there better way to save data from this json to object?

The json that i get from server looks like this:

```
{"documents": {"document": [
  {
  "id": 1,
  "description": "Lorem ipsum",
  "date": "2017-03-01"
},{
  "id": 2,
  "description": "Lorem ipsum",
  "date": "2017-04-01"
}
]}}
```

My service:

```
 downloadDocuments(id: number): Observable<DocumentsDTO[]>{
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   headers.append('Authorization', this.authorizationService.basic);
   let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
   let body = JSON.stringify(id);
   return this.http
     .post(DOCUMENTS_URL, body, options)
     .map((response) => response.json().documents.document)
 }
```

And component where I call this service:

```
documentsArray: Array<DocumentsDTO>;

downloadUserDocuments(id: number) {
   this.documentsService.downloadDocuments(id)
     .subscribe(documents =>{
       if(documents !=null){
         this.documentsArray = [];
         documents.forEach((data) => {
           this.documentsArray.push(data);
         });
       }
     });
 }
```

This solution works for me but I am not happy with .
Is there better way to save data from this json to array?

Comment: What doe it mean that you are not happy? Your problem is not really clear.

Comment: why `JSON.stringify(id);` if `id`is `3` it will produce `"3"`, not a json...

Comment: look at this line in service
 .map((response) => response.json().documents.document)
in my opinion there is better way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

**Service**

```
return this.http
  .post(DOCUMENTS_URL, body, options)
  .map((res: Response) => {
    res.json().map((obj) => {
      new Document(obj.id, obj.description, obj.date)
    })
  })
```

This should return a collection of Documents

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing how you could get past

`.map((response) => response.json().documents.document)`

This is just where your array is placed inside the response, period. You'd have to make changes to backend to change this.

What I am not understanding is why you are doing unnecessary iteration inside your subscribe, why not directly assign the array that is coming to your `documentsArray`? Like so:

```
this.documentsService.downloadDocuments(id)
  .subscribe(documents => {
     if(documents != null) {
       this.documentsArray = documents;
    }
 });
```